# Conditions for turbo boost fail?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Generally I have no trouble making a boost at the start of the race, but sometimes it fails, so that you stop immediately. I wonder if it's a random penalty for using boost or it's because of the wrong timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong timing. To successfully boost you need to press the accelerate button just as the 2 starts to fade. Any earlier will cause the burnout

Comment: For comparison it's a bit earlier than it was on Mario Kart Wii where it was around the mid of the "2" being shown.